# Android Add to Score

Tags: android

```
public class ScraperActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scraper);
        final int[] s = {0};


        final TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);
        final TextView[] score = {(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScoreDisplay)};

        final int[] displays = {184576, 38347, 28198, 643892, 38471872, 4783654, 1235433, 2324, 65344232, 43212, 63345543, 4321,
                1554534, 65432, 324154, 7658434, 13543, 64534532, 6543563, 6543342, 7645354, 543322,
                545324, 542232, 54353453, 456456, 345343453, 943242, 56454353, 1231216543, 765463532, 6453489, 43242, 54354, 5483958,
                3485304, 2132151, 42345463, 23213445, 5432908, 9649372, 754938554};
         final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEdit);

        input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                        || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                    int rando = (int) (Math.random() * displays.length);
                    display.setText(displays[rando]+"");//INTS - ALWAYS PARSE WITH "" OR TOSTRING()
                    input.setText("");
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        score[0].setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                //int rando = (int) (Math.random() * displays.length);
                String scr = String.valueOf(s[0]);
                score[0].setText(String.format("Score %s", scr));
                if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                        || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) &&
                        input.getText().toString().equals(display.getText().toString())) {
                    //s++;
                    s[0]+=1;
                    scr = String.valueOf(s[0]);
                    score[0].setText(String.format("Score%s", scr+1));

                    return true;

                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When the input text is equal to the displayed text view, the score in the score display text view should increment by 1; however, it remains at zero.  How can I make it so that it shows the increment? Is it the listener that's causing it?

Comment: `s[rando]` doesn't throw an index out of bounds exception?

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger and setting a breakpoint at the line `s[0]+=1;` to see if this bit of code ever triggers the way you expect? Or even a log message?

Comment: There was no log message nor an out of bounds exception in the terminal. There was no change in value.